# Moving columns up using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a two columns one column is size 9 and other column is size 3. I have a Google Map inside col-3 but my map is at the bottom of the screen. How do I get it to move up?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-9">
        content....
<div class="col-sm-3">
        content...
      </div> 
    <div> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: HTML and CSS sample would help as there isn't much to go one from your post to be able to help.

Comment: just put up some html

Comment: maybe a screenshot of what you are referring to as being at the "bottom of the screen"

Comment: The HTML you posted is wrong, looks like col-sm-9 is not close and there is an open tag <div> in the bottom where it probably should be a closing tag </div>

Comment: yes its supposed to be a closed </div> tag TYPO

Comment: Your question doesn't provide any guidelines for a desired solution

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the divs stacked with the 3-column div on top. If so, do it like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-pull-3">
            content....
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-pull-9">
            content...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: With col-sm-3 nested in col-sm-9 how would that work?

Comment: you're missing a closing div

Comment: Fixed. I blame the OP :P

Comment: @APAD1 u are almost there instead of stacked I want them side by side

Comment: Ok, then remove the pulls so it's like @Dan's response.

Answer (score 0):

You have your `col-sm-3` nested within your `col-sm-9`

Try this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-9">
        content....
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
        content...
     </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```